# Please explain the different behavior of 2 same jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I am learning jquery and I am confused between two situations, these 2 should work same as per me but are not working.

`$('#selected-plays li:not(.horizontal)').addClass('sub-level');`

`$('li :not(.horizontal)').addClass('sub-level');`

both of the above lines indicate the same thing as all li are in class selected plays only so I think output should be same however background-color differs in terms of area it covers, below is my complete code. Please explain the difference between two selectors above.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>

  <style>
  .horizontal
  {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:10px;
  }

  .sub-level
  {
    background-color:#ccc;
  }

  </style>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selected-plays>li').addClass('horizontal');
        $('#selected-plays li:not(.horizontal)').addClass('sub-level');
        $('li :not(.horizontal)').addClass('sub-level');
    });
  </script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <ul id="selected-plays">
    <li>Comedies
        <ul>
            <li>As you like it</li>
            <li>All's well that ends well</li>
            <li>A midsummer night's dream</li>
            <li>Twelfth night</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

        <li>Tragedies
        <ul>
            <li>Hamlet</li>
            <li>Macbeth</li>
            <li>Romeo and Juliet</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Histories
        <ul>
            <li>Henry IV</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Part I</li>
                    <li>Part II</li>
                </ul>
            <li>Henry V</li>
            <li>Richar II</li>
        </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Well, the space before `:not` does matter.

Comment: Is that a typo or a real question ?

Comment: [**learn.jquery.com**](http://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li:not(.horizontal)
```

This is li elements that do not have the horizontal class.

```
li :not(.horizontal)
```

This is li elements that contain elements that do not have the horizontal class.

Notice the space between the `li` and `:not` in the second selector.

Comment: Thanks, got my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Both the selectors will behave differently as you have entered "SPACE" after li in second one:

```
$('li :not(.horizontal)').addClass('sub-level');
```